# Rails - Searching for another class in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, parameters

I have two classes - ClassB belongs_to ClassA has_many ClassB.

I want a link in class_a/index.html.erb to create a new ClassB object based on the ClassA object selected in the ClassA index - so class_a/index.html.erb includes

```
@class_a.each do |object|
   ..object display..
   link_to 'new ClassB', new_class_b_path(pass the ClassA param to the new ClassB object here)
end
```

I thought I had to pass the param thusly -

```
new_class_b_path(class_a_id: object.id)
```

I've got the following in the ClassB controller -

```
@class_a = ClassA.find(params[:class_a_id])
@class_b = @class_a.class_bs.build
```

... But I get the following error. Where am I going wrong?

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ClassBController#new Couldn't find ClassA without an ID
```

Comment: `new_class_b_path(params[class_a_id: object.id])` it should be something like `new_class_b_path(class_a_id: object.id)` no need `params` use params[:class_a_id]` in controller to get the `params`

Comment: Hi - still no joy. I know that the object.id is valid, because I've got a line in the code checking that at the moment. It seems to be that the object.id is not being passed onto the ClassBController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new_class_b_path(params[class_a_id: object.id])` it should be something like `new_class_b_path(class_a_id: object.id)` no need `params` while you sending `params` from `view` use params[:class_a_id]`in controller to get the` params`

So it will look like

in view

```
 @class_a.each do |object|
   ..object display..
   link_to 'new ClassB', new_class_b_path(class_a_id: object.id)
 end
```

in controller

```
def new
  @class_a = ClassA.find(params[:class_a_id])
 end
```

For escape from exception you can do this in controller

```
 def new
  @class_a = ClassA.where(id: params[:class_a_id])
  @class_a.try(:class_bs).try(:build)
 end
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for your answer, however I'm getting an error saying that the id is not being passed into the controller - can you see anything wrong? I've updated the question - cheers, Dan

Comment: yes please post whole console output(log) for easy figure out

Comment: you `object.id`  is `nil` so `ClassA.find(nil)` raise the exception

Comment: Hi - in the ClassA index view I have <%= link_to 'Add ClassB', new_class_b_path(class_a_id: object.id)%><%= "object id is #{object.id}" %> - the object.id is not nil in the view. What was the edit you made to your post? cheers, Dan

Comment: please look into my edited post ... use the last controller action edited

Comment: `def new
  @class_a = ClassA.where(id: params[:class_a_id])
  @class_a.try(:class_bs).try(:build)
 end`

Comment: Thanks, that's great :) Now having trouble with the next bit but will put it in new question. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass a param through your link like below :

```
@class_a.each do |object|
   ..object display..
   <%= link_to 'new ClassB', new_class_b_path(class_a_id: object.id) %>
end
```

in your Calss b controller

```
def new
  @class_a = ClassA.find(params[:class_a_id])
  @class_b = @class_a.class_bs.build
end
```

and in your form :

```
<%= form_for @class_b |f| %>

<%= f.hidden_feild  :class_a_id %>

 ... skipped code ...


<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this, however, it doesn't seem to be passing the object_a_id through - I've updated the question :)

Comment: there is no need to pass prams in path like `new_class_b_path(params[class_a_id: object.id])` You need to pass like what I suggest in my answer